# Can you declare someone a "kafir" who denies that hijab is a part of Islam?

Tags: quran, fiqh, hijab, madhhab, takfir

Can a Muslim ask a hujjah to do gtakfir, by declaring kafir a person who denies Quranic concepts such as hijab?

Comment: Did you mean: Can a Muslim ask a Hujjah to declare a person takfir who denies that hijab is a concept based on the Quran?

Comment: Takfir is a concept by which people declare somebody a "kafir". This is regarded as highly frowned upon by early scholars and there are many ahadith warning Muslims to declare a believer a disbeliever. And AFAIK none of them practiced it. You cannot declare a person "Takfir". However anybody rejecting some orders of Allah that he knows of or believes are revealed in the qur'an is literally committing kufr (rejection).

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what exactly the person says and means by his words.

If he knowingly denies a verse of the Quran or invents an interpretation that goes against what is apparent and held by consensus then he is a disbeliever, because among the things which nullify a person's Islam are:

> أو حلل محرما بالإجماع كالزنا أو عكسه أو نفى وجوب مجمع عليه أو عكسه
>
> That one considers lawful what is forbidden by ijmaa, e.g. fornication ; or that one denies what is obligatory according to ijmaa.
>
> <sup>— [Nawawi, Minhaj al talibin](https://al-maktaba.org/book/12096/325)</sup>

Specifically regarding Hijab:

> But if what is meant by hijab is covering the head, then there is no difference of opinion among the scholars concerning the fact that it is obligatory. His rejection of both types, and his making fun of them, is apostasy from Islam ... so denying it and making fun of it is kufr which puts one beyond the pale of Islam.
>
> <sup>— [islamqa](https://islamqa.info/en/answers/115156/)</sup>

Answer (score -1):

I am not sure about it, but first we should try to educate him. If he still denies, then there is no problem in takfiring him.

Comment: why is it not a problem? Takfir is a very severe penalty. On what base should this be done?