# Can my father be my Wali if I am unsure if he can be considered a Muslim?

Tags: nikah, wali

Assalamu aleykum,
Im a sunni woman and I want to do my Nikkah but I need a Wali. My Dad is an Alevite who doesnt pray, doesnt read quran,doesnt go to the mosque, doesnt like women wear hijab but he doesnt eat pork.He calls himself a muslim alevite but im not sure if he really is considerated as a muslim. Is he valid as my Wali or should I take an Imam as my Wali? And if he cant be my Wali,do I need his consent for my Marriage?

Answer (score 1):

We do not give personal verdicts on this site.

If a person does not pray then he is a disbeliever according to some madhabs, although the majority do not consider that alone to be disbelief unless his reason for not praying is due to his creed, see [If someone do not pray 5 time, is he/she Kafer?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/a/80911/20218). Similarly if he denies hijab being prescribed in Islam then that too is disbelief, see [Can you declare someone a "kafir" who denies that hijab is a part of Islam?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/68427/). Other things related to beliefs can also render one a disbeliever.

If the father is a disbeliever then he can not be the guardian of Muslim, as non-Muslims can never have authority over Muslims.

> وأجمعوا أن الكافر لا يكون وليا لابنته المسلمة
>
> There is consensus that a disbeliever cannot be a guardian of his Muslim daughter
>
> <sup>— [Al-Ijma' - Ibn Mundhir](https://shamela.ws/book/151100/85)</sup>

When he does not act as her guardian then that means that his consent is also not relevant. In this case guardianship would be transferred to other closest paternal relations who qualify. That could be for example your grandfather or brother or uncle etc. See [Who can be wali, and in what order?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/39553/). If there is no one in your family then it goes to the ruler. If there is no ruler then any local leader of the Muslims, or you may authorize any Muslim who fulfills the other conditions. According to the Hanafi madhab you can also marry without a guardian if you are adult, sane and free.

Answer (score -2):

Nope, if he doesn't pray he's officially not a Muslim:

Jami` at-Tirmidhi 2618
Narrated Jabir:
that the Prophet (ﷺ) said: "Between disbelief and faith is abandoning the Salat."