Related to marrying a reverted muslim
ASSALAMUALIKUM I saad from India wanted to ask you that can I marry a reverted muslim who's came to Islam from past 1 year and wants to die as a muslim as she's love with the ideas culture and the practices in Islam so we both Saad and Maryam wanted to marry each other but her parents can't be witness as they don't know that their daughter is converted and my pare t won't agree at this age so we both agreed to marry ...so my question is sir that can we listen to nikah on youtube and as witness their is allah who's almighty knows what's going on in between and will our nikah will be accepted...we are marrying so that we will be away from the sins .Please reply and help us know what steps we can take to marry. I request if this Cannot be done can u please help us both by doing nikah via zoom or Google meet . Assalamualikum

The guardian in this case is not the father of the wife if he is a non-Muslim. Rather see https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/81499/
